# Ubuntu unable to locate package libyaml

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, package, libyaml

Ubuntu 20.04. Trying to install Ruby 3.2.2 I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ruby-build.20230911110842.25159.uzwoaP/ruby-3.2.2/lib/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

So I go on and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libyaml
```

But I get the following output:

```
E: Unable to locate package libyaml
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you try again with `sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev` ?

Comment: Same error with the `libyaml-dev` package

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems that there's no package named `libyaml` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Some packages that might possibly solve your dependency:

- `libyaml-libyaml-perl` (original implementation afaik)
- `libyaml-0-2` (faster C++ implementation)

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the package `libyaml` is not available in the Ubuntu repositories, which is why apt-get is unable to locate it. However, the package you're looking for is actually named `libyaml-dev`.

You can install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

After installing `libyaml-dev`, you should reinstall Ruby. If you're using `rbenv` and `ruby-build`, you can do this with the following command:

```
rbenv install 3.2.2
```

This should be it.